# How can I install the LKG version of TypeScript from the repository step-by-step please?

Tags: typescript

I wish there was a detailed instruction on how I can install the latest-known-good version on TypeScript from the source code repository. Does anyone know how to do it?

UPDATE:

Ideally I would like to use it from the Visual Studio via the plugin.

Comment: Heads up: the visual studio plugin is not open source.

Comment: This? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/29/trying-the-latest-typescript-build.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> I wish there was a detailed instruction on how I can install the latest-known-good version on TypeScript from the source code repository. Does anyone know how to do it. Ideally I would like to use it from the Visual Studio via the plugin.

## First:

> I wish there was a detailed instruction on how I can install the latest-known-good version on TypeScript from the source code repository

TypeScript now ships with nightlies : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/07/27/introducing-typescript-nightlies.aspx

## Second:

> Ideally I would like to use it from the Visual Studio via the plugin.

Documentation on how to use it with visual studio https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Dev-Mode-in-Visual-Studio

## Corollary

Atom-TypeScript https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript uses fairly up to date builds of TypeScript.